# Processing 2 lists simultaneously

Tags: powershell, foreach

I'm working on powershell script which search certain file on remote computer and pipe (save) them to xx.txt file, and sends email with attached file if scan was OK, if it was not it will just send email with error message. (I have 70 computers in domain)

Now what I what to do is join computer name with username. (I'm still very new with powershell scripting)

this is script:

```
$people = Get-Content "D:\Script\people.txt" # list of people. One user per line.
$computers = Get-Content "D:\Script\list.txt" # list of computers is stored in list.txt file. One coputer name per line
$day = (get-date).DayOfWeek # day of week
$time = get-date -Format "HH:mm:ss" # time
$date = get-date -Format  "dd.MM.yyyy" # date

foreach ($a in $people){}    

foreach ($i in $computers)

    {$i + $a + "`n" + 
                "================================================="
                "|         " + $time + " - " + $day + " - " + $date+"        |"           # 14:57:54 - Friday - 17.10.2014
                "================================================="
                "|       Testing connection on computer $i    |"
                "================================================="

                $test_connect = Test-Connection -ComputerName $i -Count 2 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue  # Ping computer with 2 counts and don't dispay errors

             if ($test_connect -ne $null) # if ping OK, continue with searching for files
                {   
                    "================================================="
                    "|          Testing connection PASSED            |"
                    "|       Scan started on $i at $a             |"
                    "================================================="

                    $RemoteSB = $executioncontext.invokecommand.NewScriptBlock("get-childitem c:\*,d:\* -include *.xls,*.xlsx,*.mobi,*.avi,*.mp3,*.mp4,*.csv,*.aif,*.iff,*.mid,*.ra,*.wav,*.wma,*.mov,*.mpg,*.rm,*.wmv,*.epub -exclude *.xlm -recurse")
                    invoke-command -computername $i -scriptblock $RemoteSB -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue > X:\$i.txt

                $smtpTo = "example@example.com"
                "================================================="
                "|              Search done on $i             |"
                "|          Continuing to next computer          |"
                "|      email report sent to $smtpTo      |"
                "|            !!!! SCAN COMPLETE !!!             |"
                "================================================="
                "                              "
                $file = "X:\$i.txt" # file name list of computers and their destination PATH$
                $smtpServer = "smtp.gmail.com" # enter your SMTP server
                $smtpFrom = "example@example.com" # send email FROM address
                $smtpTo = "example@example.com" # send email TO address
                $messageSubject = "Scan Done for computer $i on $date" # SUBJECT line
                $messagebody = "Scan for computer $i is done on $day $date at $time, continuing to next one. This computer belongs to $a." #email BODY text
                Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer $smtpServer -To $smtpTo -From $smtpFrom -Subject $messageSubject -Body $messagebody -attachment $file # Sendmail command

                }

            else # if PING fails send email with error
                {
                    "================================================="
                    "|                !!!! ERROR !!!                 |"
                    "================================================="
                    "================================================="
                    "|       Testing connection on $i FAILED      |"
                    "================================================="
                    "  "

                $smtpServer = "smtp.gmail.com" # enter your SMTP server
                $smtpFrom = "example@example.com" # send email FROM address
                $smtpTo = "example@example.com" # send email TO address
                $messageSubjectError = "!!!ERROR!!! Scan for computer $i failed" # SUBJECT line
                $messagebodyError =  "Error Scan for computer $i at $day $date on $time, continuing to next one." # email BODY text 
                Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer $smtpServer -To $smtpTo -From $smtpFrom -Subject $messageSubjectError -Body $messagebodyError # Sendmail command

                }
      }
```

Script is working perfectly if I don't put first foreach ($a in $people){}
I think something is missing in ($a in $people) {XXXXXXXXX} or alike but I still don't understand what.

If anybody can help, I will more than appreciate.

regards

Neven Gotovac

UPDATE:

Tried with answer below but it didn't work or I have put it in wrong line.
output of script look like this. If you check you will see that name "augustin" repeats always. Instead it should be changed like computer name.

```
  PS C:\Users\Administrator> D:\Script\run3.ps1
  c04 - augustin
  =================================================
  |         17:44:29 - Friday - 17.10.2014        |
  =================================================
  |       Testing connection on computer c04    |
  =================================================
  =================================================
  |                !!!! ERROR !!!                 |
  =================================================
  =================================================
  |Testing connection on c4 for augustin FAILED   |
  =================================================

  C37 - augustin
  =================================================
  |         17:44:29 - Friday - 17.10.2014        |
  =================================================
  |       Testing connection on computer C37      |
  =================================================
  =================================================
  |                !!!! ERROR !!!                 |
  =================================================
  =================================================
  |Testing connection on C37 for augustin FAILED  |
  =================================================

  C51 - augustin
  =================================================
  |         17:44:29 - Friday - 17.10.2014        |
  =================================================
  |       Testing connection on computer C51      |
  =================================================
  =================================================
  |                !!!! ERROR !!!                 |
  =================================================
  =================================================
  |Testing connection on C51 for augustin FAILED  |
  =================================================
```

@Matt 
I have put brackets as you said but it still repeats username :( is it a problem if username have dot in middle firstname.lastname in people.txt file

Comment: Is there supposed to be a relationship between the person and the computer? Like Matt said, your current code lists every person for every computer.

Comment: Yes it suppose to be relationship. Example: c01 - augustin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have yet to check all the code but one issue I see if this line

```
foreach ($a in $people){}
```

While this would work the expression assigned to it is empty `{}`. You need to move the closing brace to the end of your script.

```
foreach ($a in $people){}    
foreach ($i in $computers)

    {$i + $a + "`n" + 
                "================================================="
                "|         " + $time + " - " + $day + " - " + $date+"        |"          
                "================================================="
                #truncated to save space            
    }
```

Should be instead

```
foreach ($a in $people){    
foreach ($i in $computers)

    {$i + $a + "`n" + 
                "================================================="
                "|         " + $time + " - " + $day + " - " + $date+"        |"          
                "================================================="
                #truncated to save space            
    }
}
```

The logic you have hear whould process every person `$a` for each computer `$i`

**Update from question edit**

I think that you need to check each computer with its corresponding user, Correct? If that is the case you could itterate through a single index loop. There is a better way to do this but this would meld with your current code nicely.

```
For($index=0;$index -lt $people.Count; $index++){
    $a = $people[$index]
    $i = $computers[$index]

    $i + $a + "`n" +
    #... Process Stuff Here

}
```

Use that in place of both the for loops in your current code.

Comment: It change username when script comes to end (checks all computers)

Comment: The code is working as I indended it and now from you update I think I see what you wanted. Do you want to merge the contents of the files? Ie the user in the first line of `$people` matches the first line in `$computers`. You made it seem like you wanted to check all users on all computers. Are both text files the same length then?

Comment: Yes I wan to merge. As you understud. Yes they are same lenght.

Comment: I read the post again and saw _join computer name with username_. The title of the question was misleading as was the miscontrcuted `For` loop. I hope I got it right this time.

Comment: So, do I remove foreach ($a in $people){
        foreach ($i in $computers)        and add your For($index...)